# Is it possible to create a ketone using ozonolysis, when you have an alkene with no alkyl groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Can Butan-2-one ($\ce{CH3-CH2-CO-CH3}$) be created from Butene ($\ce{C4H8}$) using ozonolysis?

Comment: As far as I know, the ozonolysis of butene will simply yield ethanal (or ethanoïc acic, depending whether you use $\ce{Zn}$ or $\ce{H_2O_2}$)

Comment: 1-Butene or 2-butene? In both cases, the anwser is most likely that you cannot. But you could catalytically oxidize 1-butene to butan-2-one ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0167-2991(08)63439-4)).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible.

The general reactions scheme for ozonolysis is as follows: [image]

Consider the case of butene:

[image]

Herein $R_1$ and  $R_3$ can be identified as methyl groups, and similarly $R_2$ and $R_4$ are plain old hydrogens. Following the reaction scheme, one would naturally expect **Ethanal** as a product (if you use $\ce{Zn}$, ethanoic acid may be obtained if you use something else).

I'll drop by later and write out a mechanism perhaps.